# How can I tell what Vampire/Necromancer lords destroy their units once defeated?

Tags: warhammer-ii-total-war

I started a game with Von Carstein and found out fairly quickly that when Mannfred dies on the field, all of his units die as well. And when I started the campaign and took on the Templehof unit in a nearby castle, their units also disintegrated after I killed the lord just inside the gate.

So, I was thinking that all Necromancer or Vampire lords lose their units when they die. But the next battle I had was with another Templehof enemy and some support units from a nearby town, and killing the lord in that instance didn't do anything obvious to the other units and I ended up losing the fight even though I beelined for the lord.

How do I determine whether killing the lord Necromancer/Vampire will actually wipe the field?

Comment: Did they actually die immediately, or did they slowly disintegrate? If I remember right, all undead will lose HP over time when their morale is broken. That's pretty likely to happen if your lord is killed, because it probably means you were losing the battle. On the other hand, if you're just beelining for the lord, the leadership loss from the lord dying won't push them to start disintegrating because they're unlikely to be losing by enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undead in TW:Warhammer have a different response to morale than other factions. Rather than units wavering or fleeing, they start disintegrating. You can see in a unit's banner the morale value it currently has.

In the state where a regular unit would be able to rally and return to the battle, this is quite slow, but when it would be a full army rout the units quickly disappear. A common point for that to occur is an already losing army having it's general die, as the general's death is a large morale penalty.